# Exactness of the Weil restriction functor $\mathrm{Res}_{X/k}$

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, algebraic-groups

**Question.** Let $X$ be an Artinian scheme over a perfect field $k$. Consider the abelian category $\mathcal{C}$ of affine commutative group schemes of finite type. Is the Weil restriction $\mathrm{Res}_{X/k} \colon \mathcal{C} \rightarrow \mathcal{C}$ an exact functor?

Consider an exact sequence

$0\rightarrow A \rightarrow B \rightarrow C \rightarrow 0$

where $A$, $B$, and $C$ are objects in $\mathcal{C}$. For every $k$-scheme $T$, we have a left exact sequence

$0 \longrightarrow A(X\times T) \longrightarrow B(X\times T) \longrightarrow C(X\times T).$

Therefore, $\mathrm{Res}_{X/k}$ is left exact. However, I have not been able to prove whether $\mathrm{Res}_{X/k}$ is also right exact.

In my personal problem, $\mathrm{char}\,k = p>0$ and $X = \mathrm{Spec}\,k[x]/(x^p)$. Moreover, $A$, $B$ and $C$ are finite commutative group schemes.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is not right exact. Assume that $k$ is algebraically closed. If the map $Res_{X/k}B\to Res_{X/k}C$ was surjective as a map of sheaves for the fppf topology, then in particular, the map on sections $B(X)=(Res_{X/k}B)(Spec\, k)\to (Res_{X/k}C)(Spec\, k)=C(X)$ would be surjective (because every fppf cover of $Spec\, k$ has a section).

This surjectivity might well fail, here is one example. Take $X=Spec\, k[x]/x^p$ with $k$ of characteristic $p$, as in your setting, and let $0\to A\to B\to C\to 0$ be the following short exact sequence of group schemes over $k$:
$$0\to \mu_p\to \mu_{p^2}\xrightarrow{p} \mu_{p}\to 0$$
Then $C=X$ as schemes, and if the map $B(X)\to C(X)$ was surjective,then, in particular, the isomorphism $X\simeq C $ would lift to a map $X\to B$, which is to say that the map $\mu_{p^2}\to \mu_p$ admits a section (not necessarily compatible with the group structure) as a map of schemes. But this is false -- on the level of rings this map is given by $k[t]/(t-1)^p\to k[t]/(t-1)^{p^2}, t\mapsto t^p$, but any map $k[t]/(t-1)^{p^2}\to k[t]/(t-1)^p$ in the other direction sends all $p$th powers to elements of $k$.

$\newcommand{\bG}{\mathbb{G}}$We can look more closely at what exactly happens here: the points of $Res_{X/k}(\mu_{p,X})$ with values in a $k$-algebra $R$ are given by $$\mu_p(R[x]/x^p)=\{a_0+a_1 x+\ldots+a_{p-1} x^{p-1}|a_0\in \mu_p(R),a_{>0}\text{ arbitrary elements of }R\}$$
We can identify $Res_{X/k}\mu_{p,X}$ with $\mu_p\times\bG_a^{p-1}$ via the map that sends $(a,t_1,\ldots,t_{p-1})\in (\mu_p\times\bG_a^{p-1})(R)$ to $$a\cdot \log^{\leq p-1}(1+t_1x)\cdot \log^{\leq p-1}(1+t_2x^2)\cdot\ldots \log^{\leq p-1}(1+t_{p-1}x)\in (Res_{X/k} \mu_{p,k})(R)$$
where $\log^{\leq p-1}(y):=-\sum\limits_{i=1}^{p-1}\frac{(1-y)^i}{i!}$ is the truncated logarithm series.

Similarly, $Res_{X/k}\mu_{p^2}$ is $\mu_{p^2}\times \bG_a^{p-1}$, and the map $Res_{X/k}\mu_{p^2}\xrightarrow{p}Res_{X/k}\mu_p$ whose surjectivity we are discussing in fact factors through the $0$-dimensional group scheme $\mu_p$, because $Res_{X/k}\mu_{p^2}$ is almost entirely $p$-torsion.

This behavior can be attributed to non-smoothness of the map $\mu_{p^2}\to \mu_p$: it is proven in Corollary A.5.4 of 'Pseudo-reductive groups' by Conrad-Gabber-Prasad that Weil restriction takes smooth surjections between quasi-projective schemes to smooth surjections.

Comment: This also shows that the sheaf Hom functor $\mathop{\mathcal{H}\! \mathit{om}}(X,-)$ is not exact. Great! Thank you.